# How to use Keras Linear Regression for Multiple input-output?

Tags: neural-network, keras, tensorflow, linear-regression

I was trying to use [this code](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/34007/implementing-simple-linear-regression-using-a-neural-network). I put part of the parameter list, but as you see the error indicates that it's taking the first member of each list to put in the first row and second ones for the second row and so on ..

```
from pylab import *
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras import optimizers

#Generate dummy data
data = [[45,45,200,300],[44.7,45.6,50,60],[9.9,10,11,12]]
y = data*5

#Define the model
def baseline_model():
   model = Sequential()
   model.add(Dense(1, activation = 'linear', input_dim = 1))
   sgd = optimizers.SGD(lr=0.2)
   model.compile(optimizer = sgd, loss = 'mean_squared_error', metrics = ['accuracy'])
   return model


#Use the model
regr = baseline_model()
regr.fit(data,y,epochs = 4,batch_size = 1)
plot(data, regr.predict(data), 'b', data,y, 'k.')
```

But was unsuccessful cause I get this error that less argoments were expected :

> ValueError: Error when checking model input: the list of Numpy arrays
>   that you are passing to your model is not the size the model expected.
>   Expected to see 1 array(s), but instead got the following list of 28
>   arrays: [array([[  45.  ],
>          [  44.7 ],
>          [   9.9 ],
>          [  65.5 ],
>          [ 110.  ],
>          [   2.  ],
>          [   0.25],
>          [  13.  ],
>          [  17.  ]]), array([[  45.  ],
>          [  45.6 ],..

Comment: What have you passed as input?

Comment: an input with 6 cols in 28 rows and output 8 cols, 28 rows

Comment: Your inputs shapes are not what your network expect I guess.

Comment: Can you post your exact code

Comment: @dashnick the code is exactly like the one in the answer of the linked question in text above. Only that the data is changed to the configuration I explained in  second comment

Comment: You are obviously converting your data wrong.  If you don't post the code we can't help you figure out why.  Downvoting until then.

Comment: @dashnick I'm on mobile phone, don't have access now, will upload

Comment: @dashnick I put the full code. It should be clear now

Comment: Your `y` variable should be a single array

Comment: I appreciate your answer, just one thing, here I did not change the y from original code. But in reality I have to have a multiple output as well. Like a 4xn matrix. Will this work out with a single array?

Comment: In the other example `data` is reshaped into a vector, so `y` is a vector.  You'll also need to change `input_dim`.

Comment: Is the negetive vote given by you ? @dashnick

Comment: No, I don't have enough rep here to downvoting

Answer (score 1):

The primary issue is `y = data*5`. That code programmatically creates synthetic targets. It might be better to explicitly create synthetic target values.

It is better to have both features and targets defined as numpy arrays than lists-of-lists.

Additionally, there has to be one input node for each regression feature.

Here is a revised version of your code:

```py
import numpy as np
from pylab import *
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.keras        import optimizers

# Generate synthetic data
data = np.array([[45,45,200,300],[44.7,45.6,50,60],[9.9,10,11,12]])
y    = np.array([1, 2, 3]).reshape(-1, 1)

# Define the model
def baseline_model():
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(1, activation = 'linear', input_dim = data.shape[1]))
    sgd = optimizers.SGD(lr=0.2)
    model.compile(optimizer = sgd, loss = 'mean_squared_error', metrics = ['accuracy'])
    return model


# Use the model
regr = baseline_model()
regr.fit(data, y, epochs=4, batch_size=1)
plot(data, regr.predict(data), 'b', data,y, 'k.');
```